# Is Samsung's "bricking" of Note 7 devices legal?

Tags: united-states, property

Last week Samsung [announced their intention](http://gizmodo.com/samsung-is-about-to-brick-every-galaxy-note-7-in-americ-1789913643) to push a software update to all (recalled) Galaxy Note 7 devices in the United States that will effectively ***disable ("brick") those devices.*** The update will happen automatically and without the customer's prior consent.

I'm having a very hard time believing this could be legal in any jurisdiction. It's as if a car manufacturer, after issuing a model recall, sent out squads to destroy the vehicles not returned thus far.

What are the legal aspects of mass-bricking mobile phones without prior consent? How is this not simply willful destruction of people's property? What if the bricking prevents someone from making an emergency call, resulting in loss of life or limb?

Comment: Your comparison is extremely poor. It's more as if they sent squads around to lock the steering wheel and block the ignition, because that car has a proven tendency to explode when refueled or driven. The likelihood of needing this specific car to drive someone to the hospital during a heart attack or labour is negligible.

Comment: It seems almost like *conversion*, in that they are interfering in the hardware owner's property rights to continue enjoying the hardware's intended function; but that might be completely mitigated by the widely publicized fact that they are offering complete refunds. Then again, it may not fully mitigate it, since it is not generally legal to compel a refund after a sale. I absolutely agree that this move is a very bad PR move on top of a disastrous QC fiasco.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you own the mobile phone, you **do not** own the software on it - you have a licence to that software that almost certainly includes terms allowing Samsung to change the software and/or revoke your license.

Second, changing the software does not destroy the phone - the hardware is completely intact. You can present that hardware and, in exchange, receive a brand new working phone which has the added advantage that it won't spontaneously explode. Alternatively, if you are an idiot, you can install a non-Samsung OS and cause your bomb, sorry, phone, to work again.

Third, Samsung is probably not liable for any consequences that flow from an inability to make phone calls in any event - their contract will almost certainly exclude it and a case in negligence would probably fail for lack of both a duty of care and/or lack of foreseeability.

Alternatively, Samsung is aware of a real risk to the users of their phone and have gone to great lengths to get them back. Having reached a 93% return rate they have identified a way to make the remaining 7% completely harmless. It is arguable that if they can do this and don't, *then* they are being negligent.

Answer (score 0):

You may own the phone, consisting of it's hardware. And the software it runs might be licensed and not owned, but the hardware without the firmware and software likely does not fulfill the intended purpose of which the customer may have bought the phone.

When Samsung renders the hardware nearly worthless they are effectively removing nearly all of the value from the hardware.

Simply offering a refund does not always make the buyer whole in that they are out the time and effort it took to research, buy and maintain the phone, and they might not want any other phone.

I can foresee that Samsung might be liable civilly for more than just the amount of the refund for those customers that want more than a simple refund. But it probably would not be worth it to pursue Samsung.

Comment: The hardware is already worthless, since it is vastly less valuable than the equivalent that lacks a huge fire risk, doing the same job after at most the same time of usage. The argument that a customer wants this type of phone and therefore a refund would diminish the total value invested is not supported, since Samsung offers the replacement of all faulty units (as required by law in many jurisdictions, if it is possible to make such replacement).

Comment: Fires occur in all lithium ion battery packs. Samsung used two different vendors for the batteries in the Note 7. One of the vendors batteries had an issue. The hardware in its totality isn't worthless. Technologically Samsung could have found out which supplier was supplying the faulty batteries and discontinued them.

Technologically this could have been done. But Samsung opted to recall and stop shipping them, probably because of the psychological damage done to the Note 7 in the minds of the public. It's a publicity issue. Not a technical one.

Comment: `Simply offering a refund does not always make the buyer whole in that they are out the time and effort it took to research, buy and maintain the phone, and they might not want any other phone` OTOH, they are getting the money from an used phone (when did Samsung stop selling the Note?) as if it was new, and if it is not as if the other phones Samsung offers at the same price range were that different. Add (my guess) cloud storage making data migration a non-issue, and there are no damages left fo claim for.